# AFIncrementalStore and a ton of Core Data fetches

Tags: core-data, afnetworking, nsfetchrequest, afincrementalstore

I've been using AFIncrementalStore and decided to profile my Core Data fetch requests. I have no idea why the number of requests would be so large. Any fundamentals I might be screwing up?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I've figured out the problem. I'm using the service [Parse](http://parse.com) as my backend but wasn't overriding -requestForFetchRequest: to add a where clause. I only wanted items associated with the currently logged in user. This seems to have fixed things.

```objc
- (NSURLRequest *)requestForFetchRequest:(NSFetchRequest *)fetchRequest withContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context {
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[super requestForFetchRequest:fetchRequest withContext:context] mutableCopy];
    NSString *whereUserId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"where={\"userId\":\"%@\"}",[PFUser currentUser].objectId];
    [request setHTTPBody:[whereUserId dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    return request;
}
```

Now I've got a fetch request for the initial load and when I select each item. Much more appropriate.

Comment: In my subclass of AFRESTClient